# Multipage Application in AngularJs and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a web page using bootstrap and angularjs. My requirement is that I have a nav bar in my first page along with a button and form field at the centre. On clicking the button the browser should move to new page printing the value entered inside the form field at the centre of new page. Further the background of new page should be different but retain the nav bar.

I tried routeprovider in angularjs. But the new page does not print values at center nor does it change the background. It even does not pass value from previous page to new page. Kindly Help me. I am new to this context

Comment: to pass value from one page to another use filter or service and set value through controller.

Comment: If you don't show your code we cannot help you